# Best git strategy with pull-requests enforced

Tags: git, merge, pull-request

Our company is using a simple master/development/feature(s) branching model.
The number of developers continue to grow and after some "merge disasters"
we decide to close master and development to pushes and enforce only pull request with a reviewer
The question is how to merge down and up between master and development with this new strategy and how to handle merge conflicts
were we can not continue to do something like this

- git checkout master
- git pull
- git checkout development
- git pull
- git merge master
- git push -> this is not allowed

Answer (score -1):

It is not maybe an answer but in our company we decided to use gitlab server (hosted on our local servers).

Gitlab allows to disable any pushes to the branch and allow modification of this branch by [merge requests](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/). Then after review and approval, the branch (in your case master) is being modified.